# Unknown errors using csrf_token. Laravel

Tags: laravel, csrf-token

I need to connect some files, using `csrf_token` (from laravel), but i have unknown errors such as:

- `<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/app.css) }}">`
  **syntax error, unexpected ''css/app.css)); ?>">' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE)**
- `<script>
      var BASE_URL = '{{ URL::to('/') }}';
  </script>`
  **syntax error, unexpected '?'**
- `<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>`
  **syntax error, unexpected 'js' (T_STRING), expecting ')'**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

        <title>Auth</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/app.css) }}">

    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="app"></div>

        <script>
            var BASE_URL = '{{ URL::to('/') }}';
        </script>

        <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have missed a quote

instead of

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/app.css) }}">
```

use

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}">
```

Comment: Thanks, i probably need to go to bed)

Answer (score 2):

For second, instead of

```
var BASE_URL = '{{ URL::to('/') }}';
```

use

```
var BASE_URL = "{{ URL::to('/') }}";
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: While the 2nd is much easier to read, both of these actually work in `.blade.php`.